# how to pass list of values to shell argument in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Script should pass list of values to the argument and should validate if there is one argument is passed and no list.
for example 
./script --arg hi
script should do the --arg command and add/delete hi

./script --arg "hi how are you "
in this case no of arguments passed to arg how to give exception or through error if user enter above values to arg1.

```
 function test()  {
filename=$1
echo $filename
    case "$2" in
    a)
        echo $3 >> $filename
        echo "add "
        # cat $filename
        shift 
        shift
    ;;
exit
}

test $fileName $3 $4
```

Answer (score 1):

**argsCount** here will do the trick if you want to have a check on the number of the arguments passed. In the below example, I am passing 3 arguments and validation whether the arguments counts is equal to 3, if not it will exit from the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ex
set -o pipefail

copyConfigFrom=$1
hostConfigFileName=$2
hostnameEmail=$3

argsCount="$#"

if [ "$argsCount" -ne 3 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 copyConfigFrom hostConfigFileName hostnameEmail"
  exit 1
fi
```